# Can't boot to Linux USB after unplugging it

Tags: kali-linux, usb

After I installed Kali on a USB, it worked fine. 
After shutting off & unplugging, and plugging the USB back into the PC,
it no longer appears as a boot option. 
What can I do to fix this besides keeping the USB plugged in forever?

Comment: Do you have a Boot Selection menu available in your PC's boot options? Can that not find it?

Comment: @ChrisDavies I have that, but the USB doesn't show up as a boot option.

Comment: Did you install a suitable boot loader on the USB? (It's usually one of the last steps, where you're asked where to install it.)

Comment: You shouldn't need to leave your USB jumpdrive plugged in forever for it to work between reboots. One possible reason why it's not showing up anymore in the boot menu is corruption of the drive's partition table or EFI boot partition. This could be as a result of user misusing some software tools, or due to hardware corruption where some memory cells don't hold their data when USB power is interrupted. This [SE question](https://superuser.com/questions/376274/how-to-check-the-physical-health-of-a-usb-stick-in-linux) has information about testing the physical health of USB jumpdrives in Linux.